# Google Sheet Copy Column Data On Edit

Tags: google-apps-script

I had entered a formula in column B of the Google Sheet (link given below) which will generate number if I enter data in Column C.

I want to design a script which will run when data is entered in column C and the script will copy the number generated in column B in column A.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kfa9pkItGQGaWWD_L8opR9w-MZnWxA2qfBTmNYp0wmg/edit?usp=sharing

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want a script to do the following:

- Fire every time column C is edited.
- On the edited row, copy the value from column B to column A.

#### Solution:

In that case, you can use a simple [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and the corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), like this (check inline comments):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range; // Edited range, from event object
  if (range.getColumn() === 3) { // Check edited column is C
    const b = range.offset(0,-1).getValue(); // Get value from B
    if (b !== "") { // Check B is not empty 
      range.offset(0,-2).setValue(b); // Set value in A
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ Iamblichus Thanks a lot the, script works as expected and copies the content of column B into Column A, however, once the data of column B is copied in column A and after that if I delete the content of column C the data of column B will be removed as it is auto generated by formula but along with the data of column B the auto copied data in column A is also getting removed. I want that once the data is auto copied in column A it stays there even if the corresponding data in column B is removed.

Comment: @Edyphant I updated the code sample so that it doesn't update A when B is empty. I hope this is useful to you.